# Add a Php file inside a php file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add a php file inside a php file, it is not working..

```php
<?php
echo '

<p><a href="/Confusing_English/A_Lot_Of_Many.html"><strong> A Lot Of & Many </strong></a></p>

<p><a href="/Confusing_English/Already.html"><strong> Already </strong></a></p>


 <?php include 'Include/adsense.php'; ?>    

  ';
?>
```

Comment: Don't put it inside the string, put it after the string - and remove the `<?php` and  `?>` around your include.

Comment: Can you add some code whatever you have tried? It's difficult to suggest anything without knowing expections.

Comment: @Gulshan, your suggested edit changed the code - and thereby the issue from the OP. Be careful when suggesting edits so that the question itself doesn't get changed.

Comment: @Lisa you wants to echoing some strings from `adsense.php` ?

Comment: What error message you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

You have wrote everything within a string quotes (`'not executable string'`), so interpreter reads it as string, not as executable code.

There's also no need to `echo` pure HTML with PHP.

Do it as follows:

```
<p><a href="/Confusing_English/A_Lot_Of_Many.html"><strong> A Lot Of & Many </strong></a></p>    
<p><a href="/Confusing_English/Already.html"><strong> Already </strong></a></p>    

<?php include 'Include/adsense.php'; ?>
```

---

**Explanation**

There is small example of code:

```
<?php // start tag

echo 'This is not executable'; // it will just show on your screen "This is not executable"

include 'Include/adsense.php'; // let's consider is as command, PHP parser will read it as a single command, in this case it tells to include given file

echo 'Not executable either'; // part inside quotes is not executable, so it will output on the screen "Not executable either"

?> // end tag
```

I think you should read a little bit about PHP basics. Link below (w3schools isn't so good in some cases, but for basics I think it's fine).

---

**Manual**

[PHP Include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

[PHP Basics](https://www.w3schools.com/php/)

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `<?php` in a string already outputted from PHP,

Just change your code to

```
<?php
   echo '
   <p><a href="/Confusing_English/A_Lot_Of_Many.html"><strong> A Lot Of & Many </strong></a></p>

   <p><a href="/Confusing_English/Already.html"><strong> Already </strong></a></p>
   ';

    include 'Include/adsense.php';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```php
<?php

echo '<p><a href="/Confusing_English/A_Lot_Of_Many.html"><strong> A Lot Of & Many </strong></a></p><p><a href="/Confusing_English/Already.html"><strong> Already </strong></a></p>';
include 'Include/adsense.php';

?>
```